# Rust. Вызов метода у Arc<T>

Tags: rust, mutex

Читаю Rustbook и не понимаю некоторые вещи.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![1u32, 2, 3]));
    for i in 0..3 {
        let data = data.clone(); //(1)
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut data = data.lock().unwrap(); //(2)
            data[i] += 1;
        });
    }
    thread::sleep_ms(50);
}
```

(1). Метод `clone()` возвращает тип `self`, т.е. `Arc<_>`. В этом можно убедиться, если явно написать тип:

```
let data: Arc<Mutex<Vec<_>>> = data.clone();
```

В связи с этим возникает вопрос: почему в (2) мы вызываем метод `lock()` так, если бы мы работали напрямую с `Mutex`? Все как в C++, но там у `shared_ptr` оператор `->` перегружен за нас, а покопавшись в исходниках `arc.rs` я не увидел подобного или пропустил.

## UPD

Спасибо [Кнопкатык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA) за наводку на Deref coercions. Для закрепления написал такой искусственный пример:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Field {
    x: i32,
}

impl Field{
    fn print(&self){
        println!("x = {}", self.x);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Example {
    x: Field,
}

impl Deref for Example{
    type Target = Field;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Field{
        &self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Example { x: Field { x: 5} };
    s.print();
}
```

Структура Example не имеет имплементации метода `print`.
Но если вспомнить универсальный синтаксис вызова функций, то

```
s.print();
```

можно заменить на:

```
Field::print(&s);
```

Следовательно, так как у нас есть реализация типажа `Deref` для `Example`, возвращающая `&Field`, то значения `Example`, если нужно, будут автоматически преобразовываться в `&Field` при разыменовании:

```
Field::print(&Example) -> dereference -> Field::print(&Field);
```

Код, как и предполагается, выведет:

```
x = 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в механизме Deref coercions или ["Преобразования при разыменовании"](http://rurust.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/deref-coercions.html).
`Arc` реализует типаж `Deref`, значения `&Arc<T>` будут автоматически преобразованы в `&T`, когда это необходимо.
Метод `lock(&self)` Мютекса принимает `&self`, и когда мы пытаемся вызвать его с `Arc`:

```
lock(&Arc<Mutex>)
```

срабатывает механизм Deref coercions

```
lock(&Mutex)
```

а `&Mutex` это и есть `&self` для метода lock.

Comment: Да, я определенно связывал это с реализацией типажа Deref. Но меня смущает вызов `lock()` как метода, являющегося частью `Arc<T>`. Т.е. `lock(&Arc<T>)` нечто иное, чем `Arc<T>.lock()`.